# How to modify vector in shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I want to add two buttons in ui.R in shiny R. Button "Add" and "Delete" to modify a vector.

Currently only one button is OK, how to add Delete button into the code? Seems renderText() can only has one dependence.

Here is the code with one button "Add", how to add "Delete"?

server.R

```
equity_list = c()

shinyServer(function(input, output) { 
output$nText <- renderText({
input$addButton
isolate({equity_list <<- append(equity_list, input$symb)}) 
  })
})
```

ui.R

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("actionButton test"),
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput("symb", "Symbol", "SPY"),
    br(),
    actionButton("addButton", "Add")
    actionButton("DelButton", "Delete"),
    p("Click the button to update the value displayed in the main panel.")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("nText")
  )
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are better solutions out there so I will post my quick one.
You can create the two observables that listen to when the buttons when they are pressed. I have created two buttons that either add or subtract. Then in the reactive expression I have isolated the `minus` option, at the same time a `plus` option will go off at anytime it is pressed, hence it is set to as `>0`

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
equity_list <- c("AAPL","GOOG")

runApp(list(ui = pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Testing how to add and subtract"),
  sidebarPanel(actionButton("minus", "-"),actionButton("plus", "+"),
               textInput("symb", "Symbol", "SPY")),
  mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("nText"))

      ),
  server = function(input,output,session) {

    observe({
      input$plus
      equity_list <<- append(equity_list, input$symb)
    })

    observe({
      input$minus
      equity_list <<- equity_list[-length(equity_list)]
    })

    my_equity_list <- reactive({

      if(input$minus==0)
      {
        equity_list
      }
      isolate({
        input$minus
        equity_list 
      })

      if(input$plus > 0)
      {
        equity_list 
      }
    })
    output$nText <- renderText({
      my_equity_list()
    }) 
  }
)
)
```

Comment: Great, fix my problem and better solution. BTW, what's your code from? Is the answer a part of your app? Can you share your app's link? I believe I can learn more from it.

Comment: I have an analytics dashboard running for my team in a company, its not via linux box (only windows) since you can share your app via windows when you force through a port and others on the same network can connect to you. (I didnt need to set-up IIS or anything) its quite large as well. I will upload something in near future, however there are plenty of good material out there, particularly I like the apps made by these guys you can learn from them http://blog.snap.uaf.edu/author/leonawicz/

Comment: Really cool website. I created a R app base on active management portfolio theory. To calculate what's the best percentage of equities in a portfolio with lowest risk. I am converting it to shiny. So it will reactive with input.